# Port forwarding multiple internal machines all ports

Tags: ubuntu, port-forwarding

If i have 10 virtual machines and 5 machines inside a gateway of `192.168.0.1`
How can i make all of the respective machines visible publically with all ports?

Currently i have a Virgin Superhub 3. I can only forward external port to an internal single machine per port.

What are my options here?

Answer (score 0):

Port forwarding can not do this. Port forwarding is a 1 to 1 relationship.

If you want all 10 (15?) Machines to be accessible from outside the gateway, you will have to set up routing.

**Edit: adding for OP comments.**

Port Forwarding sets up a rule that takes traffic arriving at a single IP and forwards it to a different IP. For example, if the router has an external IP of 1.2.3.4 and in internal IP (which acts as the gateway for the internal network) of 172.16.0.1, you would setup Port Forwarding for 80/tcp to go from 1.2.3.4:80 to, say, 172.16.0.15:80.

Then, when traffic arrives at 1.2.3.4:80, the router will forward the traffic to 172.16.0.15:80, the internal machine at that address. You cannot forward 1.2.3.4:80 to every internal IP and expect it to work. They would all receive the traffic and reply to the router.

If you want to expose all ports on all machines inside your network to the external (Internet?) network, each machine would require a public/routable IP address connected directly to the internet/external network.

It sounds like your Virgin Super 3 is providing Network Address Translation (NAT) for the internal machines. 
[Wikipedia: Network Address Translation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation)

This works fine for client machines that are initiating outbound connections to existing services. To provide a service from your internal network facing outward, you either have to use a routable address for the server/service, or use a solution like Port Forwarding which only works for one internal address per port.

Comment: In what respect. "Routing" is very vague.